# defining a starting point for dolist

Tags: lisp

Is it possible to tell `dolist` to start at (or even better after) a certain element in the given list? As I may not want to evaluate all the elements before.

If there is no way to do so, is there any other macro which might do the job?

Considering this example:

```
(defvar *liste* #(1 2 3 4 5 6))

(dolist (x *liste* :start-after: '4)
 (FORMAT t "~a~%" x))
```

resulting in:

```
5
6
```

Comment: You might want to accept an answer, given that there are two answers here that solve your problem.

Comment: wanted to try both before giving a solution false credit. But indeed both would have done the deal, the second just proved easier and better to modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which Lisp dialect are we talking about?

Assuming Common Lisp.

`#(1 2 3 4 5 6)` is not a `list`. It is a `vector`.

```
CL-USER > (let ((v #(1 2 3 4 5 6)))
            (loop for i from 4 below (length v)
                  do (print (aref v i)))) 

5 
6 
NIL
```

With a list:

```
CL-USER 1 > (mapc #'print (nthcdr 4 '(1 2 3 4 5 6)))

5 
6 
(5 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with `NTHCDR`?

http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nthcdr.htm#nthcdr

Comment: it does do its work but i am writing a recursive function to make a binomial coefficient (forming all combinations of the elements) of a list, and therefore beeing able to use doliste in combination with a `:start-after` would ease my work a lot.

Comment: Right, but you could just start it on the tail of the list you obtain from `NTHCDR`.

Comment: You can just instead of `*liste* :start-after 4` do `(nthcdr 4 *liste*)` in the same spot, which is actually shorter and otherwise identical, because dolist would have to nthcdr down the list anyway to find a starting point.